# Manage Attributes - New Options not saving - 1.9.4.1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-options, magento-1.9.4.1

1. In Magento Admin going to catalog/attributes/
2. Choose a specific attribute, such as "Artist"
3. Go to Manage Label/Options
4. Add Option (in this case an artist's name)
5. Click Save Attribute or Save and Continue Edit
6. Either way, it does not save the new label/option and takes me back to the Manage Products Page, not back to the Attributes page.
7. Is not happening to every Attribute. For example, "Writer" works correctly.
8. The only changes recently made to the site were doing the latest Magento updates. I was a little behind on updating so I believe it covered the most recent couple of small ones. I think 1.9.3.3 was the one I had done previously. However, it has been a couple of weeks since doing the most recent updates and just discovered this issue, so the cause may be unrelated.

Have tried reindexing everything and cleaning cache and VAR folder. Tried repairing and optimizing the databases in phpmyadmin. Tried updating the Mage.php file to correct logging issue per information I could find on updating issues.

Any and all help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe you have to much options in the attribute you are trying to save and the amount of variables in the form exeeds the value of `max_input_vars`. Check that value in your `php.ini` file and increase that value, that may solve your problem.

Comment: No luck. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For anyone else who comes across this problem. It turns out it was a hosting issue. When trying to add the new attribute we were getting a 406 error. 
[image]

To fix this we had to speak with customer support at our host, who then whitelisted the process so that it would no longer produce the error. I asked how we could avoid this in the future and the reply was: "Since our apache filter is being continuously updated, there are some rules on the apache that filters some sites with the Mod_Security, and the only for us to get that error be eliminated is to whitelist it from our system's end..."

Keep in mind we are on a shared server, which continuously provides it's own batch of issues....